# MongoDB how to create role on anydatabase, I need a restrited role to only showUsers Action on any databases

Tags: mongodb

For known all databases (even with just users declared) I use with pymongo (pymongo==3.10.1 with mongodb 4.2)

```
db.command({'usersInfo': { 'forAllDBs': True },
           'showCredentials': True})
```

this command need `userAdminAnyDatabase` builtin-role on client user. 
But this role provide to much privileges. If someone crack the user password he can upgrade role to `dbAdminAnyDatabases`. 
So I failed to create a any database role with authorization (role with only `viewUser` action on any databases) for `userinfos` previous command.

any  can help me for this role definition?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [anyResource](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/resource-document/#anyresource) to get all the databases.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's i create role :

```
with pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/',
                     username='SuperAdmin',
                     password='XXXXXXXXXX',
                     authSource='admin',
                     authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-256') as client:


        extendRole="showUsersAnyBase"
        crole=client['admin'].command('rolesInfo',extendRole)
        if reinit and extendRole  in [x['role'] for x in crole['roles']]:
            client['admin'].command('dropRole',extendRole)
        if reinit or extendRole not in [x['role'] for x in crole['roles']]:
            client['admin'].command({'createRole': extendRole,
                                              'privileges': [{'resource': { 'anyResource': True }, 
                                               'actions': [ "viewUser" ]}],
                                              'roles':[ ]
                                              })
```

create connector user:

```
usersInfos=client['admin'].command({'usersInfo': [{'user' : 'connector','db': 'admin'}]})
        if reinitConnector and 'connector'  in [x['user'] for x in usersInfos['users']]:
            client['admin'].command('dropUser',"connector")
        if reinitConnector or 'connector' not in [x['user'] for x in usersInfos['users']]:
            client['admin'].command("createUser", "connector", 
                                     pwd="XXXXXXXXXX", 
                                     roles=[extendRole])
```

use the connector user with for userInfos command:

```
with pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/',
                        username='connector',
                        password='XXXXXXXXXX',
                        authSource='admin',
                        authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-256') as client2:

        usersInfos=client2['admin'].command({
                                             'usersInfo': { 'forAllDBs': True },
                                             'showCredentials': True
                                             })
        for user in usersInfos['users']:
            print("user:",user['user'],
                   "db:",user['db'],
                   "roles:",[x['db']+'->'+x['role'] for x in user['roles']])
```

Works fine !!

and connector user can't grant role:

```
        client2['admin'].command('grantRolesToUser','connector',
                                  roles=['dbAdminAnyDatabase'])
```

throw exception :

```
.....
raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: not authorized on admin to execute command { grantRolesToUser: "connector", .....
```